# Sending credentials with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, wunderlist

I'm currently trying to make a todo list on Windows Phone 8, using the API from [Wunderlist](https://wunderpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). However, I can't pass my credentials in the POST request. Here's my code:

```
public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(WebRequest request)
    {
            var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync((cb, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(cb, o), res =>
                    ((HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(res), request);
            var result = await task;
            var response = result;
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        return sr;
    }
```

And:

```
public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> Login(string email, string password)
    {
        //User Credentials
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parms.Add(email, password);


        //Request
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(API_URL + "/login");
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        // This doesn't seem to work
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
        var tr = await DoRequestAsync(request);
        return tr;
    }
    private string DictToString(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
        {
            builder.Append(kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value + "&");
        }
        return builder.ToString();

    }
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpClient`?

Comment: Also, you need to URL-encode your values.

Comment: Looks like HttpClient is much easier. I think I will try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove string with .credentials, as NetworkCredential is for NTLM/Kerberos, here is api with usual POST

before sending request add:

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write("email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email));
    writer.Write("&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password));
}
```